# Compile Warning: converting to pointer from integer of different size

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

i have very little knowledge in c.

When compiling, I get this warning:

> converting to pointer from integer of different size

```
strcpy(aux, (char*)valDate(argv[7]) );
```

when executing the compiled file, I get this error: segmentation violation.

valDate function:

```
char * valDate(char *date)
{
  char fecha[9];
  sprintf(fecha,"%4.4s%2.2s%2.2s", &date[1], &date[6], &date[9]);
  fecha[8]='\0';
  return (char*)fecha;
}
```

Comment: Hard to know without seeing what argv[7] is. Also you're returning a local pointer in valData which might work sometimes but is not the correct way to do it since the stack pointer can shift between function calls causing you to lose the pointer or have it overwritten which in your case might be happening with strcpy

Comment: `return (char*)fecha;` is wrong. You can't return a local variable

Comment: try `char fecha[9];` -> `char *fecha = malloc(9);`

Comment: argv[7] = 20211201

Comment: While it's sometimes needed, in your cases the casts you have should not be needed. Adding casts to silence the compiler is usually the wrong solution.

Comment: And you need to create a proper [mre] to show us. Have you remembered to declare the `valDate` function before attempting to call it? Have you checked that `argc > 7`? And if the supposed contents of `argv[7]` is `"20211201"` then all your indexes for `date` in the function are wrong. Remember that array-indexing is *zero* based.

Comment: Also if the contents of `argv[7]` is `"20211201"`, then why the `sprintf` to begin with? Why not a plain `strcpy`? Or considering the pointer issue in the return, why not the (non-standard but still common) `strdup` function?

Comment: And I really think you need to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget how to [edit] your questions.

Comment: Since `argv[7] = "20211201"` has only 8 characters (plus one `'\0'`), why do you access the 10th by `&data[9]`? What do you expect there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to a variable that is defined inside a function. When that function exits that variable may be destroyed/inaccessible i.e. Segmentation Violation.

Define fecha outside of the function and pass in a pointer so that the function can modify it.

Or allocate memory on the heap for that variable

```
char *fecha = malloc(sizeof(char) * 9);
```

N.B.: Whenever you allocate memory you must later free that memory. So only use this if it fits.

Comment: A problem with `malloc` is that someone later has to call `free`. Who and when?

Comment: Good point. I'll add that to the answer